# Update user id column in multiple mysql tables

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I realise that this question seems to have been asked and answered before, but I'm still unsure of whether this is possible.

I'm trying to update 9 tables to reflect a change in user_id value, a bit like this:

```
UPDATE table1, table2, table3, table4 SET
table1.id='12', table2.id='12', table3.id='12', table4.id='12'
WHERE table1.id='15' OR table2.id='15' OR table3.id='15' OR table4.id='15'
```

Is that possible? Have I missed something really obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Innodb storage engine provide support on foreign key cascade update - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

you should consider this

**Alternatively**

Break the single query to nine query (each for each table) to minimize potential risk on making mistake (play safe instead of play smart)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of UPDATE is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

it seems that you can only update one table at a time.

Comment: You are right! It is kind of odd. Is it also portable? I have used a JOIN in the where clause and also EXISTS, but never 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

update statement is very similar to select, so you should be able to do that!

However, i recommend using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

change `OR` to `AND` Otherwise you will be in the problem. `OR` will update many other user ids

```
UPDATE table1, table2, table3, table4 SET
table1.id='12', table2.id='12', table3.id='12', table4.id='12'
WHERE table1.id='15' AND table2.id='15' AND table3.id='15' AND table4.id='15'
```

Comment: That's a very good point! Not quite sure how I missed that... unfortunately purely using AND doesn't work as the id isn't in every table (ie not ever user has an entry in table4)

Comment: They Why you are using those tables in sql statment?

Comment: So that I don't have to check an entry exists in each table before I update them.